# Getting error REST API 404 after upgrade to JAVA 17 and tomcat 10.1

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-404

Getting below error when hitting REST API the first time and after that getting 404.
The issue is coming after upgrade to java17 and tomcat 17

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [RESTServlet]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javax` namespace is not supported by Tomcat 10 anymore. You have to use the `jakarta` namespace: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Specification_APIs

Comment: Can you please tell me, In which file I need to do changes

Comment: You need to update your dependencies and then change every import that uses javax to jakarta. A bit more detailed explanation: https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee